# How to change Tkinter LabelFrame border color

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to apply new style to a  Tkinter LabelFrame and update the color to red like below:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('appstyle', parent = 'alt',
    settings = {
        'TLabelframe': {
            'configure': {
                'bd': 'red'
            }
        }

    }
)
style.theme_use('appstyle')


labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text = "Group")
labelframe.grid(padx = 20, pady = 20)

left = Label(labelframe, text = "Inside the LabelFrame")
left.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but the result is still as defalt

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `'bg': 'red'` instead of `'bd': 'red'`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to guess name of the option again? Ok, here's a [link](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973) with options to each ttk widget! Just update `background` option to red!

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('appstyle', parent='alt',
                   settings={
                       'TLabelframe': {
                           'configure': {
                               'background': 'red'
                           }
                       },
                       'TLabelframe.Label': {
                           'configure': {
                               # 'background': 'red'     uncomment this to make even label red
                            }
                       }
                   }
                   )
style.theme_use('appstyle')


labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Group")
labelframe.grid(padx=20, pady=20)

left = tk.Label(labelframe, text="Inside the LabelFrame")
left.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

alt theme:

[image: alt theme]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to keep the actual border that comes with only the 'solid' relief style and color that.

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('style', parent='alt', 
    settings = { 'TLabelframe': {
        'configure': {
            'background': 'black',
            'relief': 'solid', # has to be 'solid' to color 
            'bordercolor': 'orange',
            'borderwidth': 1
        }
    },
    'TLabelframe.Label': {
        'configure': {
            'foreground': 'green',
            'background': 'black'
        }
    }
})
style.theme_use('style')
```